# How to design flexi grid component in AEM with React rendering?

Tags: reactjs, aem

Our AEM project is on headless architecture where AEM will provide only JSON to front end, where front end is responsible for building the UI using client side rendering. We would like to design the Flexi grid component where author should have the control on the layout to choose (2x2, 3x3, 4x4 with capability to merge the rows and columns). The `container Flexi grid` component should allow authors to author `image/logo/text` component in it for each tiles.

The grid component can have all inner components with same/different width & height. Below are few examples combinations of how component should support different tile sizes for each inner component.

[image: 5 Images with different size]

[image: 4 Images with different size]

[image: 4 Images with same size]

We thought of possible option as using editable template with layout container where author can drag drop image components multiple times. But this approach does not support different heights for components and also does not work with react rendering (rendering control is on front end side).

Any better design option for this?